# How can remove in dataGridView the default line in the control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the designer this is what I see:

[image: DataGrid]

The line with the red x when I add items to the datagridview this line is push down in the end I see this empty line with the red x in the bottom.

Is there any way to remove/delete this line so the dataGridView1 will be empty ?

This is after I added items this empty line is at the bottom now:

[image: DataGrid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need to set `AllowUserToAddRows` to false for this line to not show. This line is there so that a user may type in the grid and add data. By setting this property to false you will not allow users to do this and hide that row.

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Another tip, if you register on `RowsAdded` you can then set the icon properly so it does not show as a red X.

```
private void DataGridView1_RowsAdded(Object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e) 
{
    DataGridViewImageCell cell = dataGridView1[column_image.Index, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewImageCell;
    cell.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Icon;
}
```

Comment: How do I make that it will not show the red x ? I regisitered the RowsAdded event. I want to keep this line but without showing the red x in it.

Comment: Added code to answer showing an example of setting the image in this event.